# Mathematica-like (LaTeX) typesetting for own CAS application

Tags: math, latex, wolfram-mathematica, formula, computer-algebra-systems

As I am using Mathematica a lot I got the idea to write a small and free CAS which just exposes a very small subset of necessary functions and packages to be used and I want to present the results in an appropriate way to the user like Mathematica does (ignore the Facebook logo in the background :D ):

[image: Mathematica's Output]

My first idea was to create LaTeX code in the background and to `pdflatex` the source and include the PDF then in the view... however this seems way to much overkill! I want to write this CAS either in C++ or C# and I want to know if there are any recommended solutions to output nice formula like that.

My first thought was a "real-time formula editing view" but it would be ok to have an input box to enter the commands and formulas and the upper view just to be uneditable output.

Comment: Not to curb your enthusiasm but there are already several open source CAS programs. [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) and its GUI enriched pendant [wxmaxima](http://andrejv.github.com/wxmaxima/), and [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) come to mind. Projects like that are usually not one-man affairs and I feel you might be underestimating the effort involved. Additionally, I wouldn't start with thinking about how to achieve the nicest possible output, but with doing the core CAS stuff first.

Comment: I know, however i already have implemented some core components. My goal is just to practise my skills and to implement the algorithms we learn in our CAS lecture and i want to implement only a few things to get the "taste" of this :)

Comment: I may be off, but if I'd want to write my own CAS, the presentation layer would  not be among my main initial concerns. You can always make it more sophisticated later, or you could even generate Mathematica boxed expressions from your CAS expressions, and use Mathematica FE for the time being. And I probably wouldn't choose either of the languages you mentioned as an implementation language, but would rather pick some modern fast functional language with good FFI, like OCaml for instance (or LISP). Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Hi Christian. [Symbolism](https://github.com/dharmatech/Symbolism) is a library for automatic simplification of algebraic expressions in C#. It can be used as the core of a CAS.

Comment: I have repository up on GitHub that renders entered LaTeX (via KaTeX) instantly within a C++ (Qt) application.  Would u be interested in working together on a LaTeX -> CAS prototype?  Mainly for basic LaTeX formulas as a way to speak the language of the CAS.  I am really intrigued by this idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few ways come to my mind.

1. Use LaTeX behind the scenes to typeset equations, as you say. Again, Cadabra does this.
2. Use [TeXmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/) as the front end. [Cadabra](http://cadabra.phi-sci.com/screenshots.html) does this.
3. Use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). This is a javascript framework which renders TeX equations to images or MathML. It's very easy to use it if you have a HTML view in your UI toolkit. MathJax is used in the sister site [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), for example.

I find the route 3 is the most attractive.

Comment: +1 MathJax seems to be the most convenient solution for such a small project! I will have a look whether i will either show images or htmls but very cool solution.

Comment: TeXMacs would probably be the least amount of work. There's already a [standard interface for external programs](http://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/manual/webman-interface.en.html) which has been used by [many CAS](http://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/plugins/cas.en.html). Then you can concentrate on writing your CAS.

Answer (score 2):

For calling LaTeX in the background, don't use `pdflatex`, but use the non-PDF `latex` to produce a DVI file, and convert it then to PNG with `dvipng`.

Have a look at the `preview` package or the `standalone` class to get the output in the right size (i.e. only the formula, not a whole page).